# White border around png image after saving with IrfanView

Tags: transparency, png, irfanview

I created a simple circle drawing in Inkscape. Then I exported the drawing as png.

When I resize the image in IrfanView and save it as png then a thin white border appears around the circle.

You can see the difference between both images here:

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6i9c.jpg)

[Image after IrfanView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAPEh.jpg)

Why does saving with IrfanView put a white border around circle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely due to saving out a PNG-8 from IrfanView. PNG-8 has very basic transparency support, on or off. So with an anti-aliased edge like you have there, where you really need different levels of transparency, it is simply applying a transparency color map (taken from your white background color) and applying it to the pixels that aren't completely transparent.

To avoid this, make sure you are saving as a PNG-24.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Saving an image as PNG-24 is a bit cumbersome in irfanview. Here is how to make it: http://superuser.com/questions/418086/saving-image-as-png-24-in-irfanview

Comment: Actually [PNG-8 has full alpha support](http://pngmini.com), just some programs pretend it doesn't.